# ImageView of ListView loading incorrect few second when scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I'm using ListView with ImageView is a element of List. I have got problem when fast scrolling my List : The system seems to be recycling views until it loads the correct position's view in my ListView, resulting in duplicated images and text for a few seconds. After that, ImageView display images correctly. I'm using Universal Image Loader library to load images.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PhotoViewHolder holder;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.photo_item_horizonal_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new PhotoViewHolder();
        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoIcon);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }else{
         holder = (PhotoViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    //item variable is a element at position of ArrayList
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(item.getImageUrl(), holder.imgPhoto);
    ...
    }
```

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advanced

Comment: can you show us the adapter code ?

Comment: That's how ListView works.  It recycles views.  You need to fully set all UI elements on each call to getView for it to work correctly.  Post your getView, you probably don't have it right.

Comment: show your whole adapter code?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing Download Aquery from [This link](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) put that .jar File in your Lib folder and change your code to this:

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PhotoViewHolder holder;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.photo_item_horizonal_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new PhotoViewHolder();
        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoIcon);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }else{
         holder = (PhotoViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    //item variable is a element at position of ArrayList
       AQuery aQuery=new AQuery(v)
       aQuery.id(holder.imgPhoto).image(item.getImageUrl().toString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder image while image is loading . You can do that by UIL option:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
                ......
                .build();
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the image of the ImageView by yourself in a later part of the code?
if you do, you should call

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().cancelDisplayTask(holder.imgPhoto);
```

so that the library knows that the link between the image and the imageview is broken